# adb -d install prompted "device not found"

Tags: android, adb

i get **error: device not found**  out of sudden once running adb -d install.
it worked well before, and "down" once I changed SIM card in my SAMSUNG Android.

I tried to revert back ~ using old SIM card ~ seems illogical, but still I get "device not found" error.

I have set Setting * Application * Development * USB Debugging... restarted my phone, as well as my PC.

Is there any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your driver is not finding the phone. Try "adb devices" command, if the device is found it will display a number, if not it wont display anything. You may want to reinstall to your driver.

Comment: no device was listed by "adb devices"... sorry any reference how to reinstall the driver.. , and however it was worked before (few hours back)

Comment: In windows, you can do Start Menu -> Control Panel and then Add/Remove programs (Win XP).

Comment: hmm.. I am using mac.. are you saying reinstall the ADB?

Comment: No, you should not need to do so. I dont do debugging on Macs but take a look here (http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up), this may help.

Comment: hi, in the link given, for mac -- we don't need to install any driver, do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try killing the adb process and restarting it. I've noticed that the Adb sometimes refuses to recognize devices after you've been working with them for a long time.